# How to change FormBuilderDropdown selected value using setState?

Tags: flutter, flutter-form-builder

I have the following `FormBuilderDropdown` from `flutter_form_builder` definition for user to select US state

```
class _StateFormBuilderDropdownState extends State<StateFormBuilderDropdown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FormBuilderDropdown(
      attribute: widget.attribute,
      initialValue: widget.initialValue,
      validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "State (required)"),
      hint: Text('Select State'),
      items: List<DropdownMenuItem>.from(
        UsStates.states.map((s) => DropdownMenuItem(
          value: s.code, child: Text(s.name)
        ))
      ),
      onChanged: widget.onChanged
    );
  }
}
```

When I get to this screen, I do a reverse geocoding to autofill user address.

When the address is resolved, I call `setState` to change form values. The problem is that `FormBuilderDropdown` only have `initialValue` available to set the value and, as far I know, this is not evaluated again after the first build so I can't use it to change the value.

How can I change  `FormBuilderDropdown` after initial setup?

Comment: Looking at your code `widget.initialvalue` seems to be a property in the StatefulWidget. Can you place this as variable in `_StateFormBuilderDropdownState`  and check.

Comment: I installed the package and tested the `FormBuilderDropdown` widget, and it automatically sets the selected value on the dropdown. If you need to use that value  elsewhere then you should take if from the onChanged and pass it on.

Comment: @Abhilash Chandran: I don't think that will make a difference, if you check the code of `FormBuilderDropdown`, the parameter `initialvalue` is only used on `initState`. That code is not executed on every build but on the first

Comment: @João Soares: the problem is not to extract the selected dropdown value but changing it **programatically** using `setState`

Comment: @StackOverflower you are right. looks like the formsbuilder doesn't reset this value. However the basic `DropDownButton` exposes a `value` property which can be reset to achieve this. If you are interested i will share the code which also utilizes the provider package to intimate a state change rebuild.

Comment: Does `FormBuilderDropdown` take some sort of Controller? If so, yes

Comment: @RémiRousselet: it does not :(

Answer (score 3):

Reset the Dropdown to prevent error due to the setting a different list which is not having the current value in it.

```
//Create key    
final _dropDownKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderFieldState>();
            
//Reference the key
FormBuilderDropdown(key:_dropDownKey)
            
//Then reset using the key where ever you want
_dropDownKey.currentState!.reset();
_dropDownKey.currentState!.setValue(null);

//Then you can safely assign a different list of values to the drop down
```

Comment: Simple and effective, thanks a lot !

Comment: Agreed, simple and effective! Thanks! was hitting my head against this issue for almost an hour!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ValueListenableBuilder` to rebuild `FormBuilderDropdown` when value changes.

```
  ValueNotifier notifier;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: notifier,
      builder: FormBuilderDropdown(
          attribute: widget.attribute,
          initialValue: notifier.value,
          validators: [FormBuilderValidators.required()],
          decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "State (required)"),
          hint: Text('Select State'),
          items: List<DropdownMenuItem>.from(UsStates.states.map(
              (s) => DropdownMenuItem(value: s.code, child: Text(s.name)))),
          onChanged: (value) => notifier.value = value),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use UniqueKey(). In my case, i need to programmatically reset formbuildercheckboxlist value if using `initialValue`.

I posted it on another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61414131/formbuildercheckboxlist-internal-value-is-reset-but-the-checkbox-still-in-checke/61429348#61429348)

Answer (score 0):

How about making use of Keys to force Flutter to re-initialize the `FormBuilderDropdown`? Simply adding `key: const Key(widget.initialValue.toString())` should make it so that the `FormBuilderDropdown` goes through `initState` every time `widget.initialValue` changes, as if it's a completely new widget.